# Stopping a request in Tornado

Tags: python, tornado, web.py

I have a method for signing up a user, basically if the user fails
validation I want the request to stop processing so the user isn't
signed up.

```
def post(self):
       #[...]
       if isvalid(username) == False:
           print "Invalid Username"
           self.redirect("/badusername")

       print "User Is OK"
```

If I enter a valid username, 'User Is OK' is printed to the console
and everything is dandy, but if I use an invalid username, 'Invalid
Username' AND 'User Is OK' is printed to the console, the page re-
directs correctly though. How do I stop the request after
self.redirect so `print "User Is OK"` is never called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def post(self):
   #[...]
   if isvalid(username) == False:
       print "Invalid Username"
       self.redirect("/badusername")
       return

   print "User Is OK"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def post(self):
       #[...]
       if isvalid(username) == False:
           print "Invalid Username"
           self.redirect("/badusername")
       else:
           print "User Is OK"
```

Comment: This wouldn't work as I have about 20 different things to validate so I'd have to nest all the if statements together

Answer (score 1):

Just do a return, like this:

```
def post(self):
       #[...]
       if not isvalid(username):
           print "Invalid Username"
           return self.redirect("/badusername")

       print "User Is OK"
```